Is "anakattan" a suffix?
I am learning Japanese through Rosetta Stone. They stop giving translations at some point, but usually I can still search for meanings of things I'm stuck online. I see a sentence like this:
"Doushite hon o yomanakattan desuka?"
I can figure it's something like "why are you reading" cause the base "yom"... but not sure what this conjugation is. I can't find anything online around it. The picture is showing a girl reading a hard book... so is this asking why someone is doing something they probably can't do?
The girl responds "totemo muzukashii hon nandesu" which I think is "It's very hard to read" where I also think "nandesu" is like "don't you agree" as opposed to just saying "desu". Funny enough, Google translate just says "it is" for "desu" and "it's" for "nandesu" which is just quirkiness there I think :)

I will mention that besides n which is colloquial contraction of nominalizer no, you can sometimes see uses of 2 suffixes ending with n: (1) besides negative suffix -anai, there is older negative suffix -anu, which has contracted variant -an (e.g. yoman); (2) suppositional/volitional suffix -amu (which is generally -ō in modern Japanese, e.g. yomō) also developed contracted variant -an, which is used for one of meanings of particle bakari (meaning 5 here: "（「せんばかり」の形で）動作が行われそうである、行われたとしても当然であることを表す。また比喩を表す。") (e.g. yoman bakari).

(In that explanation, せん in せんばかり is such contracted -an variant of suppositional/volitional form of verb す / する ("to do"), which has morphological stem se-, so se- + -amu → semu → sen. Suppositional/volitional form of that verb created using revised modern rules and generally used in other contexts is しよう.)

This question is similar to: What is the meaning of ～んです/～のだ/etc?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

First the verb conjugation:
yomu (to read) -> yomanai (do not read) -> yomanakatta (did not read)
The 'n' part after 'yomanakatta' is a contraction of 'no' and is called the 'explanatory-no'. There are a lot of good explanations on this site. Try searching for 'explanatory の’. When used with a question it basically adds the nuance of "why is it that ...". I'm not the best person to explain it.
Adding the 'n' makes the the whole of the part before into a noun phrase and, as you know, to say 'why is it noun?' you write 'doushite noun desuka'.
Putting it all together we have 'why is it that you did not read the book?'.
You're translation of "totemo muzukashii hon nandesu" gives the right idea but is not strictly correct. 'muzukashii' is acting on 'hon' rather than the verb 'yomu', so 'muzukashii hon' is 'a difficult book'. A more accurate translation would be "it's that it's a very difficult book".
Finally, I would urge you to find some grammar resources to complement your course and, at the very least, learn hiragana. It will make it much easier to search for help. Good luck.

Thank you! I wouldn't have known to search for "explanatory の". I was looking for conjugation help! I can read hiragana... just need to figure how to write it on here now :)
